# How to write a conditional probability?

Tags: r

How to write a conditional probability like this in R :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xX7G.png)

I tried to begin with this code but the conditional probability seems very difficult to write...

```
nbr_ants=10
bifur = c(1,-1)
x1 = sample (bifur, 1)
X = rep(0,nbr_ants)
X[1]=x1

for (i in 2:length(X)){
  X[i]=sample(bifur, 1)
}
```

I've got my Xi sample but I don't see what to do next?

To clarify the conditional probability: I have a model of a bifurcation with ants that have to choose between the right and left direction.

c represent the quantity of pheromones the ants depose when they select a path;

alpha is a positive parameter ;

Zn is number of time the right path have been chosen after the passage of n ants;

Xn is the choice of the ant number n: 1 if right and 0 if left;

Does someone have an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Think about a table with n rows (one for each trail step) in which each column contains a measured variable (e.g. Zn).
Then you can add new columns to calculate the result like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# example data
c <- 1
alpha <- 1.2
# the ants are getting better over time! :)
Zn <- c(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8)
# the right door 1 is more frequently chosen at the end
Xn <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)

tibble(
  # time step
  n = seq(10),
  # number of time the right path have been chosen after the passage of n ants
  Zn = Zn,
  # choice of the ant number n: 1 if right and 0 if left;
  Xn = Xn
) %>%
  mutate(
    # intermedate result
    coef = (c + lag(Zn))**alpha,
    P_Xn = coef / (coef + (c + n - lag(Zn))**alpha)
  )
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>        n    Zn    Xn  coef   P_Xn
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1     0     0 NA    NA    
#>  2     2     1     1  1     0.211
#>  3     3     1     0  2.30  0.381
#>  4     4     2     1  2.30  0.303
#>  5     5     2     1  3.74  0.415
#>  6     6     3     0  3.74  0.351
#>  7     7     4     1  5.28  0.433
#>  8     8     5     1  6.90  0.5  
#>  9     9     8     1  8.59  0.554
#> 10    10     8     1 14.0   0.789
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Where `lag(Zn)` is the value of the column Zn in the previous row and `P_Xn` is the calculated probability depending on the previous step.